# Gutenberg core blocks - remove options

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Using core WP Gutenberg blocks is fantastic, but in certain cases I would like to refine the available options to improve my clients user experience, and avoid them having too many options.

For example, in the Heading block, I would like to remove the 'Levels' H1 & H6, as well as all of the 'Alignment' options.

In the paragraph block, I would like to disable 'Font Size' and 'Drop Cap' options.

I have scoured the API documentation with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It (How to remove the options) depends on the specific core block.

Long answer:

In some cases, a block's options are specifically hard-coded and unless you literally rewrite a new block yourself, you cannot do it.
Some people try to cheat around this by doing hacks like using `display: none` so that the panel does not display but this does not work for users of assistive technology and can break when the css used by the editor changes.

Removing the h1 and h6 in the headings block is an example of this. There is an [existing feature request](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20213) to filter the headings block.

In other cases, **there are common options (padding, margin, typography settings like font size, line height, colors) called ['supports'](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/) that are reused across several core blocks.**

These can be modified through a theme.json file.

For example, if you want to disable the drop cap option and font size options ONLY in the paragraph block, add the following to your theme.json

```
    "settings": {
    "blocks": {
        "core/paragraph": {
            "typography": {
                "dropCap": false,
                "customFontSize": false,
                "fontSizes": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to disable some settings from ALL core blocks you'd just move those declarations up a level, above the block specific listings. In the following example, you would disable users creating their own duotone patterns, from using the default duotone patterns or gradients by:

```
"settings": {
    "color": {
        "customDuotone": false,
        "defaultDuotone": false,
        "customGradient": false,
        "defaultGradients": false,
```

A full theme.json with all of these would appear like the following:

```
{
"schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
"version": 2,
"settings": {
    "appearanceTools": true,
    "color": {
        "custom": true,
        "customDuotone": false,
        "defaultDuotone": false,
        "customGradient": false,
        "defaultGradients": false,
        "gradients": []
    },
    "settings": {
        "blocks": {
            "core/paragraph": {
                "typography": {
                    "dropCap": false,
                    "customFontSize": false,
                    "fontSizes": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can also limit some of these theme.json settings via [php filters](https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-filter-theme-json-with-php/) although it's still pretty poorly documented.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [`editor.BlockEdit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) Filter. I copied the example from the handbook to persist it here.

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
 
const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>
                        My custom control
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, "withInspectorControl" );
 
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );
```

What you want to change is the blocks [`<Toolbar>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/toolbar/)-Component.

Comment: The link to the default toolbar is deprecated. Would be nice to have an actual example how to remove one specific block option within this answer so it's for me and other people to figure it out :)

Comment: This comment doesn't actually answer the question which is removing existing elements. The example above simply shows how you add a NEW custom panel to the inspector.